# How to download a Flash (SWF) file with all its dependencies?

Tags: file-download, swf

I have a URL to an SWF file and it is pointing to an interactive presentation that is loading other content while navigating through it. 
Is there some kind of Flash "crawler" that would grab and download all dependencies to my local drive so I can use the presentation offline?

Answer (score 0):

1. First Download the .swf file
2. Decompile the .swf file using the JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler.
3. Search the decompiled source for file dependencies such as flv, mp3, etc.